# Show/hide div by button

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am trying to show/hide a specific div by id depending on which button is selected, however while the correct content is being displayed, the rest of the page is being hidden. I would like that the buttons are kept on display whereas only the `divs` with the class name of `material` get hidden or shown depending on which button is selected. What is a possible way to fix this?

#### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hccnjc10/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bob").click(function() {
    var divname = this.value;
    $("#material" + divname).show().siblings().hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.material {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="type1" class="type">
  <h3>1.2 Select material v1</h3>
  <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="1">tiles 1</button>
  <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="2">tiles 2</button>
  <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="3">tiles 3</button>
</div>
<div id="material1" class="material">
  1
</div>
<div id="material2" class="material">
  2
</div>
<div id="material3" class="material">
  3
</div>
```

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/hccnjc10/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should select specific siblings.

```
 $("#material"+divname).show().siblings('.material').hide();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p5wxv6b2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try out this.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".bob").click(function () {
            var divname = this.value;
               $("#material"+divname).show().siblings('.material').hide();
                });

          });
</script>
```

In additional to that answer you can also add `active` class on each active element.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bob").click(function() {
    var divname = this.value;
    $(this).addClass("active")
    $("#material" + divname).show().siblings('.material').hide();

    $(this).siblings('.bob').removeClass("active")

  });
});
```

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p5wxv6b2/5/)

Comment: I like the active idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$(".material").hide();
$("#material" + divname).show();
```

Trick is to split both process of hiding and showing. In my understanding, this makes code simple to read and to understand.

#### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/hccnjc10/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bob").click(function() {
    var divname = this.value;
    hideAllSiblings();
    $("#material" + divname).show();
  });
});

// This function can be used to reset states of all elements
function hideAllSiblings() {
  $(".material").hide();
}
```

```css
.material {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="type1" class="type">
  <h3>1.2 Select material v1</h3>
  <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="1">tiles 1</button>
  <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="2">tiles 2</button>
  <button class="bob" type="button" name="material" value="3">tiles 3</button>
</div>
<div id="material1" class="material">
  1
</div>
<div id="material2" class="material">
  2
</div>
<div id="material3" class="material">
  3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/hccnjc10/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".bob").click(function () {
            var divname = this.value;
               $(".material").hide();
           $("#material"+divname).show();
                });

          });
```